# How to ignore ChannelResolutionException in a Spring Integration router?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

The Spring Integration router is specified as follows in the XML config:

```
<int:chain id="integrationFrontDoorQueueChain" input-channel="integrationFrontDoorQueueChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="integrationJsonPayloadTransformer" method="transformMessagePayload"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="firstScanInventoryService" method="sendMessage"/>
    <int:router ref="integrationRouterImpl" method="route" default-output-channel="nullChannel"/> 
</int:chain>
```

In the Java code for integrationRouterImpl we find the list of channels.

```
@Component("integrationRouterImpl")
public class IntegrationRouterImpl {
    private final IntegrationReferenceDataLoader integrationReferenceDataLoader;

    @Autowired
    public IntegrationRouterImpl(IntegrationReferenceDataLoader integrationReferenceDataLoader) {
         this.integrationReferenceDataLoader = integrationReferenceDataLoader;
    }

    public List<String> route(IntegrationPayload integrationPayload) {
        final List<String> channelList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Long productId : integrationPayload.getProductIds()) {
            final Set<String> channels = integrationReferenceDataLoader.findChannelsForProduct(productId, integrationPayload.getAction().name());
            if (channels != null) {
                channelList.addAll(channels);
            }
        }
        return channelList;
    }
}
```

It appeared that if the first channel in the `channelList` is not configured at all **then the 2nd one is not invoked either**.  There is the exception:

```
[org.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel bean with name 'seaActivationChannel'.
```

However, I do not see a way to catch this exception and move to the next channel

The stack flow after leaving the method route in the router is as follows:

```
2015-12-18 15:06:30,297 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler:67 - (inner bean)#8 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'seaActivationChannel'][Headers={timestamp=1450469190297, id=60c2f22b-55a0-4512-7d5c-f798ef67c8ca}]
2015-12-18 15:06:30,299 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler:140 - org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'seaActivationChannel'
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannelFromString(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:218)

……………

Caused by: org.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel bean with name 'seaActivationChannel'
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveChannelName(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:164)
    ... 74 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'seaActivationChannel' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveChannelName(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:93)
```

Comment: Where exactly you are seeing this exception?

Comment: @Aninda, See the edited post

Comment: I am not seeing a reference to 'seaActivationChannel' in your code or configuration?

Comment: And what is the sprint integration version you are using?

Comment: @Aninda, you should not see the reference to 'seaActivationChannel'. If I configure the channel then we would not have the exception.  I need to use the 2nd channel in the list regardless of the 1st channel invocation.  We use version 3 of spring integration

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all looks like you use Spring Integration 3.0.x or above. The `ChannelResolutionException` has been changed from Spring Integration 4.0 to the `DestinationResolutionException`. Although it doesn't matter.

Not sure why you haven't seen, but `<router>` supports an option which you need:

```
   <xsd:attribute name="resolution-required">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Specify whether channel names must always be successfully resolved
                    to existing channel instances.

                    If set to 'true', a MessagingException will be raised in case
                    the channel cannot be resolved. Setting this attribute to 'false',
                    will cause any unresovable channels to be ignored.

                    If not explicitly set, 'resolution-required' will
                    default to 'true'.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string" />
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
```